# Where is my profiling output when using code::Blocks IDE?

Tags: c++, optimization, compilation, profiling, codeblocks

I am trying to profile some code of mine for the very first time. I activated profiling in my IDE options and deactivated optimization. However I have no clue about where the file which contains my profiling output is.

Could anybody explain this to me?

The end goal is to know how much time is spent in each function of my code.

Comment: How did you activate the profiling options? It should produce a file called gmon.out in the directory that you run the executable from.

Comment: @NeilButterworth project > build options . Checked "profile code when executed" And nothing gets produced

Comment: @NeilButterworth my bad I didn't check the checkbox correctly. And it does indeed produce a gnome.out file. Any idea about how I can open it? apparently I can't open it with a regular text editor